# Get count of combinations of all available cases in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table like below. Members can have purchases under mutliple categories. I want to get all category combinations for members who have had purchases in more than one categeory. That is, I want to get all combinations and their counts.
For example, members A,B,C,F have had purhcase in three categories; member D only in one, and member E is in two categories.

```
 category  member  quantity
 Clothes     A          1 
 Clothes     B          2 
 Clothes     C          3 
 Clothes     D          1 
 Cards       A          1 
 Cards       B          1 
 Cards       C          2 
 Cards       E          3 
 Cards       F          3 
 Trips       A          1 
 Trips       B          2 
 Trips       C          2 
 Trips       F          1 
 Dining      E          2
 Dining      F          1
```

The output I want is like this:

```
       Categories             mem    quant_total   
Clothes    Cards    Trips      3         15             ==> members A B C
Cards      Trips    Dining     1         5              ==> Only member F

Cards      Dining              1         5              ==> Only member E
```

I can get count of categories for members who appeared in multiple categories, but don't know how to get the above results.

```
SELECT category, count(category)
FROM table
WHERE member IN  (SELECT member FROM table
                    GROUP BY member 
                    HAVING count(distinct category) > 1 ) 
GROUP BY category
```

Plz note that category combinations can be larger like 4,5,6..., and this is a toy example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Here's my solution:

```
SELECT Categories, count(member), sum(memcat_total) 
FROM (
        SELECT  group_concat(category ORDER BY category SEPARATOR " " ) AS Categories, 
                member,
                sum(quantity) as memcat_total
        FROM table
        GROUP BY member
        ORDER by categories
    ) AS SQL1
GROUP BY Categories;
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

EDIT SQL Modified to Postgres syntax (untested)

```
SELECT Categories, count(member), sum(memcat_total) 
FROM (
        SELECT  ARRAY_AGG(category || ' ' ORDER BY category) AS Categories, 
                member,
                sum(quantity) as memcat_total
        FROM table
        GROUP BY member
        ORDER by categories
    ) AS SQL1
GROUP BY Categories;
```

EDIT 2: My attempt at a Redshift version:

```
SELECT Categories, count(member), sum(memcat_total) 
FROM (
        SELECT  LISTAGG(category,' ') within group (order by  category) AS Categories, 
                member,
                sum(quantity) as memcat_total
        FROM table
        GROUP BY member
        ORDER by categories
    ) AS SQL1
GROUP BY Categories;
```

EDIT 3: dougp's comment that the spec was for members in multiple categories is correct - I had missed that point. Here is the Redshift version of my code with that problem fixed:

```
SELECT Categories, count(member), sum(memcat_total) 
FROM (
        SELECT  LISTAGG(category,' ') within group (order by  category) AS Categories, 
                member,
                sum(quantity) as memcat_total
        FROM table
        GROUP BY member
        HAVING count(category) > 1 
        ORDER by categories
    ) AS SQL1
GROUP BY Categories;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We'll start with the data.

Please provide the DDL for this next time.  It is friendlier to those providing you the free labor.

```
with "table" (category, member, quantity) as (
        select 'Clothes', 'A', 1
  union select 'Clothes', 'B', 2
  union select 'Clothes', 'C', 3
  union select 'Clothes', 'D', 1
  union select 'Cards', 'A', 1
  union select 'Cards', 'B', 1
  union select 'Cards', 'C', 2
  union select 'Cards', 'E', 3
  union select 'Cards', 'F', 3
  union select 'Trips', 'A', 1
  union select 'Trips', 'B', 2
  union select 'Trips', 'C', 2
  union select 'Trips', 'F', 1
  union select 'Dining', 'E', 2
  union select 'Dining', 'F', 1
),
```

Then we aggregate the cagetories and get the counts

For PostgreSQL:

```
counts as (
  select member as mem
  , STRING_AGG ( category, ', ' order by category ) as categories
  , count(distinct category) as category_count
  , sum(quantity) as quant_total
  from "table"
  group by member
)
```

or for Redshift:

```
counts as (
  select member as mem
  , LISTAGG( category , ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category) as categories
  , count(distinct category) as category_count
  , sum(quantity) as quant_total
  from "table"
  group by member
)
```

Then we get the results:

```
select categories
, count(distinct mem) as mem
, sum(quant_total) as quant_total
from counts
where category_count > 1
group by categories
order by 1
```

I couldn't test the redshift code, but I tested this on an Oracle fiddle and it works.

```
with "table" (category, member, quantity) as (
        select 'Clothes', 'A', 1 from dual
  union select 'Clothes', 'B', 2 from dual
  union select 'Clothes', 'C', 3 from dual
  union select 'Clothes', 'D', 1 from dual
  union select 'Cards', 'A', 1 from dual
  union select 'Cards', 'B', 1 from dual
  union select 'Cards', 'C', 2 from dual
  union select 'Cards', 'E', 3 from dual
  union select 'Cards', 'F', 3 from dual
  union select 'Trips', 'A', 1 from dual
  union select 'Trips', 'B', 2 from dual
  union select 'Trips', 'C', 2 from dual
  union select 'Trips', 'F', 1 from dual
  union select 'Dining', 'E', 2 from dual
  union select 'Dining', 'F', 1 from dual
),
counts as (
  select member as mem
  , listagg ( category, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category ) as categories
  , count(distinct category) as category_count
  , sum(quantity) as quant_total
  from "table"
  group by member
)
select categories
, count(distinct mem) as mem
, sum(quant_total) as quant_total
from counts
where category_count > 1
group by categories
order by 1
```

Comment: I'm using Redshift... Getting error near `', ' order by`

Comment: You tagged this with [postgresql] so I used the `STRING_AGG` function as documented.  You'll probably want to use the `LISTAGG` function ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html ). I don't quickly find a redshift fiddle page, so I can't test